# AxiosError: Request failed with status code 40X

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, fetch

`hello im begineer to reactjs and imoracticing. i got problem here and i cant find the solution. i even regenerated api token and past in in .env file also the url
im using strapi cms for backend
I used axios library to fetch data from api but it gives error 404 first it gave 403 now 404

```
REACT_APP_API_TOKEN = 8bf07e7137c455bd18d24b31b0248398cd9a253eddf845d0c9b661072c85ad1057d3dcc02c22d07d70cb22c94eb7f2f8ebf9792871a1112350c1ce21d3db1cedfad5f3811fd168e5b819bad76979e7684973837bb8cab5f01df07d64dbb2211e1336d9b37780bbb6deb3bcf8f89a029eb9c3882c7d0f8f866f33fe50ac3fd59d
REACT_APP_API_URL = http://localhost:1337/api
```

//this is .env file

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sh5IF.png)
this is that file which i mentioned above
i have also import axios from axios

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MgvTb.png)
this is my strapi

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YeXie.png)
this is api folder where im getting all the data from strapi where i upload images

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ouai.png)
this is the error`

Comment: it needs a space between "bearer" and Token.
Authorization: "bearer " + process.env.REACT_APP_API_TOKEN

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have two problems in your code to be addressed

### 403 Forbidden

- missing space after type of "Authentication scheme"
- `Authorization: Bearer xxxxxxxxxxx`
- [image]
- [RFC 6750 > Section 2.1. Authorization Request Header Field](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6750#section-2.1)

### 404 Not Found

- address like this cannot never exists `http://localhost:3000/localhost:1337/api/products` (you have localhost with port twice in the URL)
- this part is not shared with us
- reasons may be two

  - wrong variable `process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL`
  - more probably default base url for axios `localhost:3000`

Answer (score 0):

```
Authorization : Bearer token
```

There is patter we should follow as above one.
Check your token with console whether it is being passed, also if the passed token is valid since your request giving 40x response.
Your axios configuration should be identified what type of authorization being passed